# Making Conditional isdigit()

Tags: c++

First look at my code:

```
#‎include‬ <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    cout << "Enter two digits" << endl;
    cin >> a >> b;
    if (isdigit(a))
        if (isdigit(b))
            cout << a+b << endl;
        else
            cout << "Invalid Digit";
    return 0;
}
```

So as we type something output only blank space.
What I want to do is print if the user hit non digit or any Alpha
program should Display Invalid string or if the user hit any Digit it must show the sum of two digits

Comment: I think you are not properly able to manage if-else ladder. Try using conditional operators.

Comment: The simplest fix of your existing code: read two `char`s, check they are digits, convert to `int`s before adding: https://ideone.com/SSoiMt **I am not claiming this is good code, just the closest to your existing code that will work!** Making it "nice" is a different matter, and why I am not making this an answer.

Comment: @Jon: [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) actually takes an int. (yet I agree, in this case it is both useless and giving wrong results ; )

Comment: @Jon: Yes sorry, took me too long to edit my post, showing that I agreed with you. Just trying to make it clearer that you can use it on an int, but NOT this way.

Comment: @BoBTFish as you post the code near my code but the pro is still exist that your program is reading only one character as char support only

Comment: @AdN you right but can't we convert char to int while program execute thats how it may work and get more than one char

Comment: @user2663691: From your verbing of the problem, it might also be you need to refresh a bit your CPP. I think what you call "more than one char" would be a `std::string`. Then, I can only strongly recommend you to use the header only **<boost/lexical_cast.hpp>**, and it will allow you to convert at runtime a string to an int with `string source = "1234"; int target = boost::lexical_cast<int>(source)`.

Comment: @AdN i do not want to be use any external lib can't we do that Directly with static_cast

Comment: @Jon `isdigit` can only be called on an `int`; calling it with a `char` results in undefined behavior on most machines.  But the `int` has a restricted range: `[0...UCHAR_MAX]` or `EOF`.  (It's a horrible interface if `char` is signed, and it often is.)

Comment: @Ramiza: You understand header only is only an include (no actual binary to link to). You cannot static_cast a string to an int if that is your question... the compiler will complain a lot, and for very good reasons :)

Comment: @Jon It's undefined behavior to pass it a `char`.  If you have a `char`, you have to cast it to `unsigned char` first, or the implicit conversion may result in a violation of the constraints on the input.

Comment: @Jon than what is the Solution for that

Comment: @JamesKanze: I just had to look that up (found it at C99 7.4/1) because my C was never that good. You have to love what happens when mixing C and C++ (since this is not a problem in pure C). Thanks for the pointer and the opportunity to freshen up, I appreciate it.

Comment: @AdN  i had seen this this http://www.scribd.com/doc/158192497/Convert-ASCII-to-Character-and-Character-to-ASCII-Code-Using-C thats why i ask

Comment: @Ramiza: Using `isdigit` in this case is wrong. You are confusing "digit" with "number". An `int` can not possibly NOT be a "number", so testing AFTER the input is read. The scribd page you are refering to just converts a `char` value to `int` so that the actual numeric value can be printed. So if you enter 0, the number printed will be 48 - this has to do with how `cout` works, and doesn't help what you are trying to do [unless I've misunderstood what you are looking for - see discussion below about the difference between "number" and "digit"].

Comment: ok so what is your final code for this @MatsPetersson

Comment: @Jon It's a problem in C, _and_ in C++ if you use the functions in `<ctype.h>` or `<cctype>`.  It's not a problem with the functions in `<locale>`.  In practice, if you're doing any sort of text processing at all, you'll want to implement the corresponding functional objects, and you'll write them to take a `char`; the implementation will either use the `std::ctype<char>` in `<locale>`, or do the cast to `unsigned char`, which ever is more appropriate to your application.

Comment: @Ramiza: See my answer - does it not work for you?

Comment: @JamesKanze: IIRC in C it's not quite that bad mainly because character literals and return values of char-manipulating functions are of type `int`. Wrong?

Comment: @Jon Character literals, yes.  But who calls things like `isdigit` on a character literal.  You know up front whether it is a digit or not.  For the char-manipulating functions, it depends.  And even in C++, `std::cin.get()` returns an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're reading into `int` variables, anything you enter has to be integers or the input operator will fail. If you want to read *characters* and check if they are digits, you should read into `char` variables, and then you need to convert them to the proper integer values before operating on them.

Try something like:

```
inline int to_int(const char ch)
{
    return ch - '0';
}

// ...

char a, b;
if (std::cin >> a >> b)
{
    if (std::isdigit(a) && std::isdigit(b))
        std::cout << to_int(a) + to_int(b) << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "One is not a digit\n";
}
else
    std::cout << "Error in input\n";
```

---

If you just want to input two generic *integer* values, then you're already on the right track, you just need to make sure the input is okay:

```
int a, b;
if (std::cin >> a >> b)
    std::cout << a + b << '\n';
else
    std::cout << "Error in input (most likely not integers in input)\n";
```

Comment: thats the only Question how to Convert this can we use static_cast

Comment: I'm 99% sure that what the OP wants is to check if the input is "valid integer", not that it's actually a "digit". This is a problem in some languages, where "number" and "digit" and "integer" are pretty much considered the same word.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is not at all what you are wanting to do.

`isdigit` returns true if the value passed in is digit. That is true if the input, interpreted as a character is a digit. This is UNLIKELY what you want, because if we assume traditional European language and ASCII character encoding, the `isdigit` will be true if the value in `a` or `b` is in the range 48..57.

What you, I presume, want to do is check if `a` and `b` are valid integer values. In which case:

```
 if (cin >> a >> b)
 {
    cout << a + b << endl;
 }
 else
 {
    cout << "Invalid digit" << endl; 
 }
```

would be the right thing to do.

Comment: "If we ignore non-European languages"... and EBCDIC, and any number of older encodings (but I think EBCDIC is the only one relative to C++ today).

Comment: Yeah, and how many beginner programmers do you know that work in EBCDIC? The above code is not part of some huge project that needs to run on 100 different OS's and 63 different types of hardware, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @Mats i want to do is just take the digits in a , b and return the sum as a+b but if the user hit any wrong digit such as q,w,e,r,t,y than program should detect that its not a valid digit and return Invalid Digit

Comment: Exactly @MatsPetersson

Comment: Right, so we have a "naming problem": in English there is a difference between "digit", which '0'..'9', and the term "number", which is 113, 7, 12, 42, 912121, 4711, and such like. Do you actually only want a single digit, or a number? [a C or C++ `int` represents a number, the correct representation for a digit is, as Joachim points out, a `char`, but then it comes in at an offset from the actual integer value, so it needs to be converted to do math on it].

Comment: ya Exactly the same @MatsPetersson but how will you Convert that

Comment: What do you want? a single digit input (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and nothing else) or an integer (0, -5, 46, 812, 19768, 40000000, etc)?

Comment: @MatsPetersson That's not the point.  There's no sense in telling a beginning programmer that `isdigit` returns true for values in the range 48-57, because that is really irrelevant and misleading, and may lead him to make the wrong assumptions.  `isdigit` returns true if the argument, interpreted as a character, corresponds to a decimal digit in the basic execution character set.  (`isdigit` is, curiously, locale independent.)

Comment: @MatsPetersson all i want is just extend the char to read more than one character than i can easily convert this to int ia static_cast

Comment: @Ramiza: Eh, no, if you want to read a sequence of digits (123, 496, etc), you should use what I have posted above - it checks if there is SOME ERROR in the input, which includes very large numbers (11139823221983279812918) and non-digit input (1abc). And either way `static_cast` will not convert the input of multiple characters to the corresponding integer value.

Comment: @MatsPetersson i am asking bcoz i had seen this http://www.scribd.com/doc/158192497/Convert-ASCII-to-Character-and-Character-to-ASCII-Code-Using-C

Comment: @Ramiza: See my comment above - yes, `static_cast` will convert `char` to `int`, but only as a "move the binary digits from one type to the other", which means that '4' will come out as 52 - which is, I don't think, what you wanted. Since `cout` treats `char` as "print the corresponding character", you can't output the numeric value of a `char` without converting it to another type that `cout` treats as an "number", where `int` is the most convenient for that.

Comment: ohh i got you point @MatsPetersson the scribd page was illustrating me